# Spring - intercept request and handle differently if domain is different

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have multi-domain application. 
It means that:
1. Main application with main domain is used to show it to the world and for customers to manage their data..
2. Customers present their data to the world through own domains which point the main app

I need to be able to intercept the request and handle it in my own way if it is coming for every other domain than main one. 
How can I do that? Any good examples of complete solution of request interception and that kind of controller?

Comment: you may use a spring interceptor listening on all request. It intercepts the request, executes the logic and it can redirect to the most suitable controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter` for that.

Here is a simple example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44844042Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44844042Application.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class DomainFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
        private final Map<String, String> redirect = new HashMap<>();

        public DomainFilter() {
            redirect.put("localhost", "http://www.google.com");
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final String domain = request.getServerName();
            if (redirect.containsKey(domain)) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(redirect.get(domain));
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    @RestController
    public static class HomeController {
        @GetMapping
        public String home() {
            return "Welcome";
        }
    }
}
```

Run it and try to open `http://localhost:8080` it will redirect you to `www.google.com` but `http://127.0.0.1:8080` still accessible.

Comment: How is it injected to filter chain?

Comment: @Component makes it visible for spring and spring in turn doing all the job for filter registration